# Server-side address validation in Craft Commerce 3

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, validation, plugin-craftcommerce3

Was wondering how to do this in Commerce 3 as there were a few different older methods discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

According to Luke, this is the preferred method for Commerce 3.

In a custom module or plugin:

```
Event::on(\craft\commerce\models\Address::class, \craft\base\Model::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES, static function(\craft\events\DefineRulesEvent $event) {
    $rules = $event->rules;
    $rules[] = [['firstName','lastName'], 'required'];
    $event->rules = $rules;
});
```

Some more details about what kind of rules you can add here, if you want something more complex than a list of required fields:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators

Comment: thanks @Gterrill